# Fastest stable duplicate removal algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, duplicates

I have an array and I need to get out of it array, without duplicates. I must leave those unique elements that have a minimal order in the original array. That's roughly I mean

```
NoDuplicate(A, value)
  for int i = 0 to i < A.length
    if A[i] == value
      return true
    i++
  return false

StableRemoveAlgo(A)      
  for int i = 0 to i < A.length
    if NoDuplicate(result, A[i])
      result.append(A[i])
  return result
```

If there is a faster algorithm than this simple one?

**UPDATE:** I cannot sort an array. I need a "stable" version of duplicate removing algorithm. So, if `A[i] == A[j] and i < j` algorithm must remove element `A[j]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you're traversing the array, put every (unique) element that you encounter into a hash table or a tree. This will enable you to quickly check -- while examining `k`-th element -- whether you've encountered the same number in the previous `k-1` elements.

A tree would give you overall `O(n log(n))` time complexity. A hashtable with a good hash function will do even better (potentially `O(n)`).

Answer (score 2):

If the domain of the elements is finite (and not too large) you can do a binary counting sort. That would be O(n).

Otherwise, you can use a temporary Hashtable to store the elements as you iterate over the array, and put the element in the output array only if the item is not currently present in the hashtable. That would be O(n) in typical case.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need O(1) space, simply make an array of indices to the elements of the original array (initially 0,1,2,...,n-1), and sort them, using the index number to resolve comparisons between elements that otherwise compare equal. This is the standard method for building a stable sort on top of an unstable sort. After that, you simply run through the array of indices to find the elements you want to remove from the original array.

Comment: Maybe you mean O(n) extra-space instead of O(1)?

Comment: I meant what I said -- if you don't need the solution to work in O(1) space, you can use the O(n) space approach I offered.

Comment: Oops. It's just my insufficient knowledge of English. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to do things in-place and sort the array? If you do it is very simple:

```
sort(array) // use a stable sorting algorithm of your choice.
i = 0 //how many unique elements we have already spotted
j = 0 //how many array elements we have checked

while(j < arr.length){
    //found a new value:
    array[i] = array[j];

    //find next value in array that is different
    while(j < arr.length && array[i] == array[j]){
        j++;
    }
}
arr.length = i;
```

---

If you need to implement a stable sorting algorithm yourself the simplest is probably Mergesort.

In this case however you can instead directly adapt the merge routine to ignore similar values (giving precedence to the earlier ones) instead of returning all of them.